# firebase-ui for email verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've set up Firebase email/password authentication successfully using firebase-ui.

```
 var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
        signInOptions: [
            // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        // Terms of service url.
        tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
    };

    // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

but for security reasons I want the user to confirm her/his email.But fromthe above code it doesn't send a verfication mail to user.
So I've used following method to send a verification mail to user if he/she not verified his/her account mail.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user && user.uid != currentUid) {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
            currentUid = user.uid;

        else {
        //---- HERE YOU SEND THE EMAIL
            firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
            }
```

But when I used this code it sends multiple verification mails for same account. Which means this method runs each time a user reload the page. It would be really greatful if someone could help me to identify whether verification mail sent or not for a specific user using firebase.

Comment: Firebase Authentication does not track whether a verification email was sent to an address already. It simply send (within reasonable limits) an email when you call `sendEmailVerification()`. If you want to throttle this sending, you'll have to implement a mechanism for that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response Frank. Is there any option to send an email verification using firebase-ui at the moment of creating a new account??

Comment: It seems that [`sendEmailVerification()` is only called in test code](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sendEmailVerification&type=) (one of the advantages of FirebaseUI being open-source is that you can search for this type of thing yourself), so it doesn't seem to be a feature. There is a [feature request for it](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/21) already, so you might want to chime/vote there.

Comment: Why don't you send the email when they sign up instead? Thereafter if they aren't verified show a message that they should verify, or resend the email (as a button/link). I've not used the UI library before as using the API directly is simple but hopefully there is some callback once signed up

Answer (score 6):

I found what seems to be a better answer to this barely-documented (for JavaScript) Firebase issue in the sample code [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#example-with-all-parameters-used):

```
  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {

        var user = authResult.user;
        ...
        if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)
        {
            console.log("new signin");
            user.sendEmailVerification();
        }
        ...
        return true;
      },
```

enjoy!

Comment: Mate, you just saved me basically 2 weeks of work with this. ```authResult.user.sendEmailVerification()```.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late but if someone finds it like me:

```
if(currentUser.metadata.creationTime === currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime)
```

Is true when it is a new user, so you have to send the verification email.
You can also do it within signInSuccess, no need to look on onAuthStateChanged

Comment: Using `creationTime/lastSignInTime` from `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't seem to work.  If the user reloads the page, for example, then likely the email will get sent again because it doesn't count as new signin.

Comment: ...Using `creationTime/lastSignInTime` with `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` should work but there is a better way: see my answer in this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SignInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback to send email verification. What you need to do is provide a callback function and check if the user has verified email, if not, sendEmailVerification.